# Both phrases mean “mutual respect”. What’s the difference?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between saying 相互尊重 and 柤互尊重.  I heard Chinese foreign minister use the latter phrase.  But does 柤互 on its own mean anything, and why use this instead of the former phrase?  柤 vs 相?

Answer (score 2):

I think you saw the phrase in writing rather than hearing it. The pronunciations, meanings, and uses of these two words are very different.

**相** has the following pronunciations:

- **[xiāng] - 交互**。(相互 [xiānghù] - each other, mutual)
- [xiàng] - 容貌，物体的外观, 察看，判断....

**柤** has three pronunciations:

- [zhā] - 同“樝（楂）”。果木名。即山楂。
- [zǔ] - 通“俎”。古代的祭器。
- [zū] - 春秋时楚地名。故址在今江苏省邳州市西北。

Comment: Thanks.  You are right - I listened again and it did sound like “xianghu”.  What’s puzzling is that when I used google translate, 柤互 translated to “mutual”.  So I thought it had a different nuance.  I guess google translate just ignored the 柤 and translated 互.

Comment: Yes, it's quite puzzling. Here is the result from my Google Translate: 柤互[Zhā hù] - Piaohu. When reverse translating, Piaohu - 飘忽[Piāohū] :) No, I think it (柤) was simply a typo of "相".

Answer (score 0):

Haha, the characters 相 and 柤 look deceptively similar, especially in small print!

Can't find a word: 柤互zhāhù

It seems the Artificial Intelligence that writes the subtitles, or translates, is not so intelligent!

Answer (score 0):

The latter one (柤互尊重) is not correct, maybe it's the wrong spell of 相互尊重.